# Count a categorical variable based on a group over time (the date column)

Tags: r, dplyr, rolling-computation

Say I have the following `data`:

| date | name | rolename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2009-12-01 | John | helper |
| 2010-12-01 | John | helper |
| 2011-12-01 | John | senior helper |
| 2012-12-01 | John | manager |
| 2009-12-01 | Will | helper |
| 2010-12-01 | Will | senior helper |
| 2011-12-01 | Will | manager |
| 2012-12-01 | Will | senior manager |

I am trying to count the number of roles, based on the column `rolename` for the person in the `name` column, the person has worked to date. For example, for the above data, I want a fourth column which measures the number of positions a person has worked so far:

| date | name | rolename | nopositions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2009-12-01 | John | helper | 1 |
| 2010-12-01 | John | helper | 1 |
| 2011-12-01 | John | senior helper | 2 |
| 2012-12-01 | John | manager | 3 |
| 2009-12-01 | Will | helper | 1 |
| 2010-12-01 | Will | senior helper | 2 |
| 2011-12-01 | Will | manager | 3 |
| 2012-12-01 | Will | senior manager | 4 |

My failed attempts:

```
#attempt 1
library(dplyr)

data %>%
group_by(name) %>%
mutate(nopositions = count(rolename))

#attempt2
library(runner)

data %>%
group_by(name) %>%
mutate(nopositions = runner(x = rolename,
                            k = inf,
                            idx = date,
                            f = function(x) length(x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the order by `date` is assured,

```r
library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(noposition = cummax(match(rolename, unique(rolename)))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 8 × 4
#   date       name  rolename       noposition
#   <chr>      <chr> <chr>               <int>
# 1 2009-12-01 John  helper                  1
# 2 2010-12-01 John  helper                  1
# 3 2011-12-01 John  senior helper           2
# 4 2012-12-01 John  manager                 3
# 5 2009-12-01 Will  helper                  1
# 6 2010-12-01 Will  senior helper           2
# 7 2011-12-01 Will  manager                 3
# 8 2012-12-01 Will  senior manager          4
```

We might get away without `cummax`, except that if a `name` returns to a previous `rolename`, its `noposition` will *decreases* (revert to a previous value). However, we want to keep the most-recent max value.

This does assume that `unique` preserves the natural order of the first-occurrences. If something goes amiss with this (I cannot think of something off-hand), we could do a window of words:

```r
quux %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(noposition = sapply(seq_along(rolename), \(i) length(unique(rolename[1:i])))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 8 × 4
#   date       name  rolename       noposition
#   <chr>      <chr> <chr>               <int>
# 1 2009-12-01 John  helper                  1
# 2 2010-12-01 John  helper                  1
# 3 2011-12-01 John  senior helper           2
# 4 2012-12-01 John  manager                 3
# 5 2009-12-01 Will  helper                  1
# 6 2010-12-01 Will  senior helper           2
# 7 2011-12-01 Will  manager                 3
# 8 2012-12-01 Will  senior manager          4
```

This produces the same results here, and it will tend to perform more poorly with larger groups (as it is iterating a lot more). I offer it as an extension in case assumptions preclude the use of `cummax(match(..))`.

Comment: Thanks, @r2evans! Your `cummax(match(..))` solution works nicely. Appreciate it.